# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when referencing a struct property

Tags: c

Not entirely sure as to why I'm getting this error, I get the same outcome even when using a single Product or an array of Products.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "salesbase.h"

//Function Declarations//
struct Product new_product(int id, char name[120], float cost);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct Product testitem = new_product(0, "yes", 2.0);
    printf("%f\n", testitem.product_cost);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

struct Product new_product(int id, char name[120], float cost){
    struct Product temp;
    temp.product_id = id;
    strcpy(name,temp.product_name);
    temp.product_cost = cost;
    temp.product_discount = 0.00;
    return temp;
}
```

salesbase.h

```
#ifndef SALESBASE_H_
#define SALESBASE_H_

struct Product {
    int product_id;
    char product_name[120];
    float product_cost;
    float product_discount;
};
struct Sale {
    int sale_id;
    struct Product sale_items[100];    
};
#endif
```

Comment: `strcpy(name,temp.product_name);` should be `strcpy(temp.product_name, name);`

Comment: It's also a bit unusual to return a structure by value for something like this.  It makes much more sense to pass a pointer to the structure to be initialized.  That way you avoid the unnecessary structure copy.  This isn't a bug, it's just a bad design choice.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `strcpy` is getting a bad address passed to it.

Here is the (relevant) output of `valgrind ./test`:

```
==21217== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21217==    at 0x4C2DC8F: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21217==    by 0x400632: new_product (in /tmp/a.out)
==21217==    by 0x4005BE: main (in /tmp/a.out)
==21217== 
==21217== 
==21217== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==21217==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x400734
==21217==    at 0x4C2DCAF: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21217==    by 0x400632: new_product (in /tmp/a.out)
==21217==    by 0x4005BE: main (in /tmp/a.out)
```

Maybe try swapping the arguments `name` and `temp.product_name`. I think the man page also give the following function definition: `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`.

EDIT: Some accuracy changes

Comment: You shouldn't have used valgrind for this. And not may be, must.

Comment: @jblixr Just giving resources for future bug fixing!